# Reshaping 3 dimensional array to 2 by stacking matrixes horizontally

Tags: matlab, reshape

I have 4x3x2 array:

```
A(:,:,1) = 
 1 10 100
 2 20 200
 3 30 300 
 4 40 400  

A(:,:,2) = 
 5 50 500
 6 60 600  
 7 70 700
 8 80 800
```

I want to reshape it to B matrix with size 8x3 preserving the structure of each matrix as:

```
 B = 
 1 10 100
 2 20 200
 3 30 300 
 4 40 400
 5 50 500
 6 60 600  
 7 70 700
 8 80 800
```

Any idea how to do it in a simple and neat way?

Answer (score 1):

As seen [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/282896-change-a-3d-matrix-to-a-stacked-2d-matrix).

Method 1: permute and reshape

```
B = reshape(permute(A, [2 1 3]), size(A, 2), [])'
```

Method 2: cell -> matrix

```
B = num2cell(A, [1 2]);
B = vertcat(B{:})
```